# Reading floats from a .txt file in C++

Tags: c++

Hello I am having trouble reading a list of floats separated by spaces in a .txt file.  I want to store the numbers read from the file in a vector and then derive some information from them (sum, median, mode and so on) but I can't even get the values stored in an vector.  The code segment is below:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

std::ifstream myFile;            //creates stream myFile
 myFile.open("simpledata.txt");  //opens .txt file

std::vector<double>numberlist;  //vector to store the numerical values in
double number = 0 ;      
while(myFile >> number){    //
    numberlist.push_back(number);

for (int i = 0; i < numberlist.size(); i++){
    std::cout << numberlist[i] << std::endl ;
}



double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i< numberlist.size(); i++){   //calculates sum
    sum += numberlist[i];}
std::cout << "Average number: " << sum/numberlist.size() << std::endl;  //prints average
}
```

When I run this program, the average is outputted as  "-1.#IND" which is obviously not what I want.  I'd really appreciate any help.  I'm very new to programming so my apologies if this code is particularly bad.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading correct file ? Show some texts from file.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much, this code is better than a lot of newbie code we see.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code

```
std::ifstream myFile;            //creates stream myFile
myFile.open("simpledata.txt");  //opens .txt file

if (!myFile.is_open())  // check file is open, quit if not
{
    std::cerr << "failed to open file\n";
    return 1;
}
```

It really looks like you are failing to open the file, and that's why you fail to read any floats.

This code will test that theory. When you open a file *always* check that the open succeeds.

Comment: Thanks!  You were correct my program was failing to open.  Will heed your advice about checking a file opens in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One tricky point about reading and writing floating point numbers from/to text files is that the standard library takes the locale into consideration. This means if the locale defines the decimal mark to be a comma then it won't be able to parse numbers with period decimal marks.
You should check your OS's locale settings and the numbers in text file, decimal marks should be the same.